# Terraform Error: Reference to undeclared resource in GCP

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to take a snapshot of a disk image in GCP using Terraform. When I run my code I get an error that says:

```
terraform plan

Error: Invalid data source

  on main.tf line 14, in data "google_compute_disk" "sqlserverdisk":
  14: data "google_compute_disk" "sqlserverdisk"  {

The provider provider.google does not support data source
"google_compute_disk".
```

For some reason the error is claiming that the `google_compute_disk` isn't supported by the google provider. This is my code:

```
// Take a disk snapshot in GCP
// Configure the Google Cloud provider
provider "google" {
  credentials = file("btgcp-iaas-dev-1463eaccc185.json")
  project     = var.project
  region      = var.region
}

data "google_compute_image" "sqlserverdisk" {
  family  = var.image_family
  project = var.project
}

data "google_compute_disk" "sqlserverdisk"  {
  family  = var.image_family
  project = var.project
}

resource "google_compute_snapshot" "snapshot" {
  name        = var.snapshot_name
  source_disk = data.google_compute_disk.sqlserverdisk.name
  zone        = var.zone
  labels = {
    my_label = "value"
  }
  storage_locations = [var.region]
}
```

How do I get beyond this error?

Comment: You have a typo: you reference a data with name `sqlserverdisk`, but you named it `sqlserverimage`.

Comment: Ok, if I correct that type-o I get this error back:

```Error: Invalid data source

  on main.tf line 14, in data "google_compute_disk" "sqlserverdisk":
  14: data "google_compute_disk" "sqlserverdisk"  {

The provider provider.google does not support data source
"google_compute_disk"```

Comment: There is a `resource' with the name `google_compute_disk`, but I can't see a `data` source with the same name. Try changing `data` to `resource` and see if that helps. Documentation: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_snapshot#example-usage---snapshot-basic.

Comment: ok thanks I will try that.